# How to update javascript variable value in html without a page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I am collecting a text area value(number in decimal ) using its id to a javascript variable, adding another variable value (number in decimal), and displaying the result in same html page

text area code:

```
<div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="num" name="count" type="text" size="5" maxlength="3"  value="" /></span></div>
```

passing value to var and adding it to another var

```
var a = document.getElementById('num').value;
var b = 1000;
var c = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
```

passing var c to div id test

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = c;
```

html for test id

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

But here, whenever I am updating the text area with new number, the final output is not updating instantly.I have  refresh the page manually to get new value. Is there anyway I update the value without a page refresh ?

Comment: Where is your jQuery and where did you define the variable `data`? And further more.. how are you doing this? With a click event?

Comment: @putvande : 'data' was a typo.variables are a,b and c.there is no click,iwould like to update the value whenever I type in textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's going to update whenever you type into the input, you need an event handler:

```
document.getElementById('num').onkeyup = function() {
    var a = 1000 + parseFloat(this.value);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = a || 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4kSN/2/)

Comment: Note that there is no need to `parseFloat` the `1000` number. Also note that this does not work on paste or any other inputs than keyboard, use appropriate event for your needs (the `input` event comes to mind).

Comment: @David - the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) is not really widely supported

Comment: agreed, but there are other ways to simulate it for older browsers, f.ex using `setInterval`. I’m just mentioning it in case the OP needs to care for pasters as well.