# Query while typing in a textbox like Netflix

Tags: javascript, node.js

When you search using the textbox in netflix.com, the URL updates automatically on what you type. It changes to something like https://www.netflix.com/search?q=test. The results also updates automatically or in real time.

I would like to know how this was done. Not the DB query part but more of the real-time/automatic update of the results with the use of GET functions. I was wondering if this could be done using Node.js, and javascript? Where should I get started?

Kind of related but not important: I saw this question with a fiddle code but didn't contain DB query and not updating the URL.
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900348/how-to-update-javascript-variable-value-in-html-without-a-page-refresh)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 0):

All of this is JavaScript, but specifically there are two parts to this.

For the first, the fetching of fresh data, this is done via the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).  (Or on older sites, XHR/AJAX.)  Using this API, the client-side JavaScript can make an HTTP request to the server and read the response.  What is used server-side (like Node.js) isn't important... most anything can be used for this.  (Node.js though is awfully convenient... it's my preferred method, but it isn't a requirement that you use it.)  With the response data, it's parsed and injected into the page however the script wants to do it.

The second part you're asking about is the URL change.  This is often done with the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).  That way, the developer can control what the URL says.  This allows the user to bookmark this particular page for later use.